# how to make background color from bright blue to dark blue using css/html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

im trying to make my website background start as a light blue background color and end up with slightly darker blue.

is there a way to code it? or should i put an image as the background(if no other option) ?

here is the image with the exact colors i want my background to have :

please ignore the clouds in the image, and check the colors only.

[image: background colors image]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: i have tried to make strips of background each with darker color, the result were horrible, it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(skyblue, darkblue);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `linear-gradient`

```css
.background{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, cyan, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try linear-gradient. [Click here for more information](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

See this for more information on which browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/?search=linear-gradient

Here's an example:

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0000FF, #000044);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```